# can not print with specific windows account

Tags: windows-7, printing, user-accounts

I can not print from my account even I have the permissinos to print, but from another account it is possible.
the problem just occures when I use adobe reader and microsoftword, but from my browser doesn t.

Comment: Can you add more details on the issues? How is it not printing? Is there a permission error, or some other printing error? Add as much details as possible so we'll be able to help out more effectively.

Comment: when I press on print nothing happes, the icon on the notification bar shows 0 documents pendinings for my account on windows. that just occures with adobe reader and microsoft word, for example a pdf file can be printed from google chrome. there is no permision errors but I guessed the problem lies with my local account cause it does not happen on other accounts.

Comment: Is the printer installed locally, or is it a network/shared printer? Can you print test page from Devices and Printers?

Comment: the driver is installed on my pc, and is uptodateز yes I can print the test page and I have used a tool from Hp to fix problems but it shows me that everything is okay.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help me.what I didn t understand the same pdf file can be print if I opened it with google chrome but from adobe reader can not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run [`flushprinters.bat`](http://jesusnjim.com/pc-repair/printers/stuck-print-jobs.html#solution0) which is a script that automates removing files which are sometimes stuck in the print queue.

I would recommend opening a command prompt and running the script from there, so that you can review any errors that may pop-up.

1. Save the batch script above to an easy to find folder, such as `c:\temp\`
2. Hold down the Windows key and press R (`Win+R`) to get a `Run` window. Type in `cmd.exe` and hit Enter.
3. When you're at the command prompt, type `cd \temp` and hit Enter.
4. Type `flushprinters.bat` and hit Enter, and wait until the script finishes.
5. Try to print something.

Hope that helps!

[edit]

For win9x, the batch file merely clears the documents from the spooler folder (e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\spool\PRINTERS\*.*`).

For other windows versions, it stops the `spooler service`, clears those files, and then restarts the spooler service.